# SQL Server: Reset Identity If Error Occurred

Tags: sql-server, identity

I have the following table:

```
create table testTable
(
    id int identity primary key,
    string varchar(256),
    constraint testConstraint unique(string)
)
```

with the following trigger:

```
create trigger testTrigger 
on testTable
for delete as
begin
    declare @max_ int
    select @max_= max(id) from testTable

    if @max_ is null   
        set @max_ = 0
        DBCC CHECKIDENT ('testTable', RESEED, @max_)
end
```

Executing the following commands:

```
insert into testTable(string) values ('test') --identity = 1
insert into testTable(string) values ('test') --error thrown because duplicate key but **identity = 2**
insert into testTable(string) values ('test1') --due to erroneous identity increment identity = 3
```

The first insertion sets identity = 1, the second throws an error because of unique(string) constraint but **identity is erroneous set to 2**.

The question is how do I make it so that errors do not increment identity?

Is there a **do-all be-all feature of SQL Server** where the identity is ensured to be produced in a sequential fashion based on what's **already** in the column/table? Thus all edge cases such as this will be captured.

Thanks in advance (:

Comment: I think you are putting to much emphasis on having perfect data. Gaps in an identity are perfectly normal and expected. It increments on every insert attempt, that is by design. And gaps also appear when a row is deleted. You could use a sequence if your are on 2012+ but it will still have gaps when a row is deleted.

Comment: thanks @SeanLange, could you provide a guideline as to how to create this sequence? I don't have any knowledge on it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+sequence&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Remember that even with a sequence you are going to get gaps when rows are deleted. Trying to fill in those gaps is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @SeanLange that was the most helpful link of my life! Would my current trigger not apply? That's what the trigger is for.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, don't worry about gaps in the identity column coming from `DELETE`s.

If you absolutely need an increment number with no gaps in it, you could handle that on the SELECT side when needed.

For example, see [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) ... this can be used along with sorting on a timestamp column of your linking (something like [SYSUTCDATETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql)) to get the exact sequence of addition for rows, `ORDER DESC`, with `ROW_NUMBER()` in the query.

This will **NOT** be tied to the data, because if rows are `DELETE`d, these ROW_NUMBERS *will* change.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any need to prevent gaps in an identity column. It sounds like you might be applying business logic to a surrogate key, which kind of defeats the purpose. You could do a sequence as Sean Lange points out in the comments.

Comment: This is really a comment not an answer. To be fair, the only valid answer here would be "No there is no way to do what you are asking". :)

Comment: Haha, the thing is this is for a business so therefore I need to apply business logic.